# OWIN use SignalR and prevent 'HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden'

Tags: asp.net, .net, owin, katana

I'm hosting SignalR in an OWIN selfhosted app - in Azure, like so:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.MapSignalR();
    }
...
```

Easy enough, works fine. Exposes `/signalr/hubs` as expected.

What I would like to do is prevent an HTTP 403.14 when someone hits the `/` url. Requesting `/` returns an HTTP 403.14:

> HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden

I think it would be nice to hide OS and hosting details by returning an empty response in case the 'root' url would be hit. So I would like to do this:

```
app.Map("/", builder => builder.Use((context, func) => context.Response.WriteAsync(string.Empty)));
```

However - the mapPath argument "/" is not allowed - it cannot end with a slash.

```
app.Use((context, func) => context.Response.WriteAsync(string.Empty));
```

This also overwrites the SignalR virtual folder (`/signal`) and thus makes the hubs unreachable.

This is the equivalent of having emtpy index.htm pages in web app folders in the old days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your own Middleware (thats the beauty of OWIN) to handle these requests. Ive made an example where it will return statuscode 200 and return empty:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.Use<OnlySignalRMiddleware>();
        app.MapSignalR();
    }
}

public class OnlySignalRMiddleware : OwinMiddleware
{
    public OnlySignalRMiddleware(OwinMiddleware next) : base(next) { }

    public override Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
    {
        if (!context.Request.Path.HasValue || context.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/signalr"))
            return Next.Invoke(context); //continue the pipeline

        context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
        return context.Response.WriteAsync(""); //terminate the pipeline
    }
}
```

If you want you can also remove some headers by doing:

```
        context.Response.Headers.Remove("Server");
```